# After insert trigger error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a trigger that after an insert on a table insert multiple rows in another table.

This is my trigger

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT
  ON a_table
  FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
  cursor parts is
     SELECT id, part FROM parts
     WHERE :new.id = parts.id;

BEGIN
  FOR part in parts
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO parts_tb2
    (id,
     part,
     name)
     VALUES
     (part.id,
     part.part,
     :new.NAME);
  END LOOP;
END my_trigger;
```

But when building the trigger I get `PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end of file" excepted ;`.

Where am I missing a ;? Am I missing a keyword somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER my_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON a_table
FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    CURSOR c_parts IS
        SELECT id, part FROM parts
        WHERE :new.id = id;
    BEGIN
        FOR v_part in c_parts LOOP
            INSERT INTO parts_tb2 (id, part, name)
                VALUES (v_part.id, v_part.part, :new.NAME);
        END LOOP;
END my_trigger;
```

Comment: Can you add a little explanation of what you fixed that was wrong in OP's code?

Comment: I didn't fixed nothing. His code it's ok, however I think his problem is something related with endlines or a hidden symbol in his code, for that I re-wrote it for more clarity, because I cannot write comments on others answers.